# How to print lists with different types in Ocaml?

Tags: list, printf, ocaml

I'm working with lists in Ocaml, so I wrote a function that prints the content of the list.
Here's my code:

```ml
let leastB = [false; true; true; true; true; false; false; false; true]
let leastI = [-16; 4; 7; 3444; -100]

let prListInt l =
    Printf.printf "[";
let rec prListIntrec l =    
    match l with
    [] -> Printf.printf "]\n"
    | g :: []-> Printf.printf "%d]\n" g
    | g :: t -> Printf.printf "%d; " g; prListIntrec t
in
    prListIntrec l


let prListB l =
    Printf.printf "[";  
let rec prListBrec l =  
    match l with
    [] -> Printf.printf "]\n"
    | g :: []-> Printf.printf "%B]\n" g
    | g :: t -> Printf.printf "%B; " g; prListBrec t
in
    prListBrec l


let () =
    prListB leastB;
    prListInt leastI
```

It's working fine, but do I need to have a new function for every type of data or is there a way to unify those functions ?

Any hints for improvments in the code (is it idiomatic Ocaml ?) ?

Comment: This is pretty much a textbook example of a use case for higher-order functions. Have you learned about that yet? Is this an assignment or exercise? Because it sure looks like one

Comment: check out `Batteries.dump` which is useful for printing arbitrary objects

Comment: It's an exercise, I'm learning from a book (with no solutions), preparing for a course next semester.
I have not learned about higher order functions, yet, nor do I know what it means.

Comment: A higher-order function is a function that takes another function as an argument (or returns a function), usually in order to specialize a small part of a more general algorithm. `List.map` is an example of a higher-order-function. What is the title of the section you're currently on?

Comment: Making Lists ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way to print a list of things in OCaml is to use the standard `Format` module, which, by the way, provides the `pp_print_list` function, that takes an item printer, a separator printer, and the list and prints a list of said items, e.g.,

```
let pp_comma ppf () = Format.fprintf ppf ",@ "

let pp_int_list ppf ints = 
  Format.fprintf ppf "[%a]" 
    Format.(pp_print_list ~pp_sep:pp_comma pp_print_int) ints

# Format.printf "@[hello = [%a]@]@\n" pp_int_list [1;2;3];;
hello = [1, 2, 3]
```

The `pp_print_list` function has type

```
?pp_sep:(formatter -> unit -> unit) ->
(formatter -> 'a -> unit) -> 
(formatter -> 'a list -> unit)
```

I.e., it is a function that takes two functions (one of which is optional) and returns a function that prints a list. If we will omit the `pp_sep` parameter for brevity, then we can say that `pp_print_list` takes an `'a` printer and returns an `'a list` printer, where printer is a function of type `formatter -> 'a -> unit`. The `pp_print_list` function is a so-called higher-order function since it takes another function as a parameter. In functional programming in general and in OCaml in particular, higher-order functions are very common, so nobody actually makes a big deal of it.

Since OCaml doesn't have any introspection facilities and the type information is erased during the compilation, there is no generic pretty-printing facilities in the language, beyond the `Format` module. Therefore, for each newly defined type we have to provide a printer, i.e., a function of type `formatter -> t -> unit`, where `t` is our new type. This is an idiom common to many statically compiled languages, cf. with Haskell's `Show` class or implementing the `<<` function in C++. There are no type classes or overloading in OCaml, therefore there is no official or canonical name for the printer function, but there is a convention to name such function `pp`, cf `Int.pp` and `Float.pp`, etc in the Janestreet's Core library.

If we will go back to your solution, then it could be easily seen that `printListBrec` and `prListIntrec` are basically the same, they only differ in the way how the items are printed. Therefore, we can parametrize such function with a function that takes a value of the list item type and, for example, translates it to a string type, e.g.,

```
let rec prGen prItem l =  
  match l with
  [] -> Printf.printf "]\n"
  | g :: []-> Printf.printf "%s]\n" (prItem g) g
  | g :: t -> Printf.printf "%s; " (prItem g); prGen prItem t
```

This function would be already more generic, though a little bit non-idiomatic. Since translating to a string and then printing is not very efficient (why to create an intermediate object if we can print it directly), we use printers and `%a` specifiers (see the corresponding Printf and Format modules for the description of the printers). Finally, we do not use camelCase in OCaml (despite that OCaml is OCaml).

Comment: Thnak you, but you still need a function for each type ?

Comment: I have expanded the answer, and I hope it will be a little bit more clear now. Though some concepts that I mention might be confusing on the first reading, they should become more clear, once you will go further through your textbook. I'm answering more or less directly to the question as it was posted, but I have a feeling, that you're more interested in higher-order functions, rather in printing facilities per se.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the two function you might see that they are nearly identical except for the `%d` vs. `%B`.

Now one way to unify them would be to pass the format string as argument. But with the black box magic that is behind format strings that isn't the easiest. It's also not a general solution as not all values can be printed with a simple format string.

So to make this even more general you can pass a function that prints out one element of the list and unify all the remaining logic about adding "[", "; " and "]" and iterating over the list.

In your case constructing the functions to print one element is trivial because ocaml uses currying. You simply use `(Printf.printf "%d")` and `(Printf.printf "%B")`. In other cases more complex functions can be passed to print more complex list elements.

PS: Not giving any source because this could be homework. The info here should get you started in the right direction.